# How to add attributes to a label generated with Zend/Form in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, label, zend-form2

I'm adding forms to my page using Zend/Form.

I'm adding elements by defining them as follows:

```
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'value',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'id' => 'value',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off',
                    'placeholder' => 'Cost',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => 'Cost',
            ),
    ));
```

As you can see there is a 'label' => 'cost' node, this generated a label to go with the input element.

How do I add classes, attributes to this label ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Please try this, i haven't tested or used this, but going by the source it should function properly:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name'       => 'value',
    'attributes' => array(),
    'options'    => array(
        'label_attributes' => array(
            'class'  => 'mycss classes'
        ),
        // more options
    ),        
));
```

If this does not function, please leave me a comment. If it won't function, it is not possible using this approach, since the `FormLabel` restricts the `validAttributes` quite a bit:

```
protected $validTagAttributes = array(
    'for'  => true,
    'form' => true,
);
```

Comment: Hello Sam,

I've changed the element as follows:

        $this->add(array(
          'name' => 'value',
          'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id' => 'value',
            'autocomplete' => 'off',
            'placeholder' => 'Cost',
          ),
          'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Cost',
          ),
          'label_attributes' => array(
            'class'  => 'css',
          )
        ));

Still no luck though.

However, it's being rendered as: <label for="value">Cost</label>

Any idea about the "for" ?

Comment: I will have to check this out later, can't promise anything though the framework points out that this will work: `$element->setLabelAttributes(array('class' => 'control-label'));` Maybe try adding `label_attributes` as a sub- of `options` - see the editted version

Comment: Under options ! =) So leave the edited version for the world to see! ;-)

Comment: Do this in the view, always. Your view must not leak into your classes.

Comment: @mike While genereally I agree, Forms - in general - are an extreme edge case of web-development. Forms SUCK. You CAN NOT DO FORMS RIGHT. Forms will always be a mess. Assigning the CSS-Class per default in the Form-Object that is supposed to be automatically rendered is prefectly fine.

Comment: I disagree. Can you provide some arguments why they suck? My forms are unit testable and provide my system with perfect, fully validated input from the user.

Comment: @mike Forms suck because - by very nature - they are a component that are both Model and View layer. They are intertwined, they can not be disconnected. Of course you can have a great Form Component, but that doesn't mean that they still don't suck ;)

Comment: Well its people who bind objects into forms and mix models with the view then. Component itself is handy when used the right way.

Comment: @mike indeed. When talking about a component like Zend\Form that is most often what you want to do. I'd argue that more experienced programmers don't bother with Forms anymore. They write InputFilters and Mapper / Hydrators but leave the form completely to the frontend guys - which in my experience as well is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

This works well in Zend Framework 2.3 :

```
$this->add(array(
  'name' => 'userName',
  'attributes' => array(
      'type'  => 'text',
      'class' => 'form-control',
      'placeholder' =>'Username',
  ),
  'options' => array(
      'label' => 'Username',
      'label_attributes' => array('class' => 'control-label')
  ),

));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$element->setOptions(array('label_class' => array('class' => 'control-label')));
```

Produces code like this:

```
<label class="control-label">
  <input type="radio" name="option1" id="option1" value="1">
  Option 1
</label>
<label class="control-label">
  <input type="radio" name="option2" id="option2" value="2">
  Option 2
</label>
```

I have tried this. It works in Zend Framework One.

Note if you use

> $element->setOptions(array('label_attributes' => array('class' =>
>   'control-label')));

you get the undesirable effect for some reason of

```
<label attributes="control-label">
  <input type="radio" name="option1" id="option1" value="1">
  Option 1
</label>
```

Comment: `I have tried this. It works in Zend Framework One.` That's great, but this is a ZF2 question, it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

For programmatic approach on ZF2+ try this:

```
$element->setOptions(array(
    'label_attributes' => array(
        'style' => 'color:gray;'
    )
));
```

Inspired by Damon's answer.